# sql query is not working after adding descending order conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Well, I have a list of jobs that I want to display so candidates can apply for the job. The problems is, the listing keep showing the old jobs and not the new one. I try to put the DESC query but it's become error.

This is what I have on my database;

[image]

and when I input the original query, it's working

original;

```html
 <?php

          $limit = 4;
    
   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id_jobpost) AS id FROM job_post";
              
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
             
   if($result->num_rows > 0)
    
          {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $total_records = $row['id'];
            $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);
          
    } else {
            $total_pages = 1;
          }

          ?>
```

and this one is after I add the DESC

```html
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id_jobpost) AS id FROM job_post ORDER BY DESC";
```

but this error came out

**Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobportal\jobs.php on line 148**

and the result doesn't come out in descending order.
what should I do to resolve this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have missed the column you want to order your result by:

```
"SELECT COUNT(id_jobpost) AS id FROM job_post ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but now the error comes out as ->Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: You probably forgot the `;` at the end of the previous line

Comment: $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id_jobpost) AS id FROM job_post ORDER BY id DESC";

Comment: Oh...that's so silly of me. Thank you. Now it's working just fine. :D

Answer (score 1):

You need column name in your order by clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(id_jobpost) AS idCount FROM job_post ORDER BY idCount DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The Syntax is:

```
 SELECT COUNT(id_jobpost) AS id FROM job_post ORDER BY column1 DESC;
```

Here column1 refers to the column that is to be sorted.